# Prompt for AD credentials on every OAuth2 authorize request

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs3.0

We have an application with its own authentication, for which we recently added OAuth2 support. A corporate customer can specify the data for his ADFS or Google domain, and we use that to automatically sign up and log in their users.

Now, the problem is switching credentials. When we log out from our application, clicking the login button (which redirects to the configured ADFS OAuth2 authorize endpoint) will immediately validate the user and send him back to our app, with a valid code for his current credentials.

The Google endpoint has a special parameter, `approval_prompt`, which we can use to force an intermediate step, at which the user can switch his credentials. I don't think ADFS has that.

What other solutions do we have? Is it possible to configure something on the ADFS server that would prompt the user to enter his credentials for every authorize request?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue with OAuth and ADFS. Based on what I read, it appears I can append `prompt=login` to `/adfs/ls/authorize`, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: For us adding the parameter prompt=login to que URL is working with OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

Here's how those url parameters work, as best as I understand them:

- wa is the operation we're requesting. So far, I've only seen two values: wsignin1.0 and wsignout1.0
- wfresh has something to do with the max age of cached credentials, but I don't entirely understand it. 0 means don't use cached credentials.
- wtrealm is the AppID configured in ADFS. This tells the ADFS server which app is trying to authenticate. For us, this is the base url of the app.
- wctx is some app-specific data returned to the app from the ADFS server after the request. Since we're using the standard System.IdentityModel setup, it handles parsing and reacting to this value, not our code. There's an ru parameter encoded inside it. This is the return url. This is how we get back to the page we came from.
- wct is the timestamp of the authentication request

Comment: So... Any idea what can I use? :-)

Comment: These parameters are for ws-fed not for oauth.

Answer (score 0):

For us adding the parameter prompt=login to que authorization request URL is working with OAuth2 :

> /adfs/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&resource=YYY&redirect_uri=ZZZZ&prompt=login